# How to get the midpoint of several latitude and longitudes in android google maps

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a shipping project where application draws the poly line of previous 6 hours updated lat and long information of a particular ship. whenever i completed this my google map camera should move to the midpoint of those lat and long. then only i can give the exact map camera view.

my problem is i cannot find the midpoint of several lat and long.

I tried the below code it only returns the midpoint of 2 lat and long which is starting and finishing lat and long.

```
 public static LatLng midPoint(double lat1,double lon1,double lat2,double lon2){

    double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);

    //convert to radians
    lat1 = Math.toRadians(lat1);
    lat2 = Math.toRadians(lat2);
    lon1 = Math.toRadians(lon1);

    double Bx = Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(dLon);
    double By = Math.cos(lat2) * Math.sin(dLon);
    double lat3 = Math.atan2(Math.sin(lat1) + Math.sin(lat2), Math.sqrt((Math.cos(lat1) + Bx) * (Math.cos(lat1) + Bx) + By * By));
    double lon3 = lon1 + Math.atan2(By, Math.cos(lat1) + Bx);
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Math.toDegrees(lat3),Math.toDegrees(lon3));
    return latLng;
//       System.out.println(Math.toDegrees(lat3)+""+        Math.toDegrees(lon3));



}
```

i need to find the midpoint of all lat and long which are all used to draw the poly line.

Anyone help me guys.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using the simple average?  average latitude = sum of the latitudes divided by the number of points; similar for longitude.

Comment: Yeah man.. It does work.. thanks.. i tried many things.. i searched a lot... But its simple avg calculation... Thankssssssss